# how to simule a focus and enterkey with js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, enter

well, as you see i have to create a function who can add a number in an input and then simulate i focus on the input and enter. i write this, but dont work if dosnt have the focus first

```js
    var kakaroto = $("#datatables_filter :input");
    var koku = kakaroto.val("545");
    kakaroto.trigger(jQuery.Event('keypress', { keycode: 13 }));
```

Comment: Have you tried using `kakaroto.focus();`?

Comment: Please post the relevant HTML as well so we can replicate your issue.

Comment: the html is a cdn and the only access i have is the console, i want to put a val in the input and keypress automatic to search. thats all